# Http status is not OK: modify headers

Tags: angular, http-headers

Developing for the first time an angular 6 project after several projects in AngularJS I encounter a CORS problem (at least that's what I think..)

What I want and always did is to retrieve my data from a mysql server. I know, Angular cannot talk directly with Mysql.
Therefor I use this php API: https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api

I have success with http.get() but not with http.post(). 
The console throws an error: a 404 error and the message: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

Reading all the answers here on Stackoverflow I think it has something to do with modifying headers. So I added headers to my post request as you can see in my code. No result however. 
My project is running on localhost:4200 and the api I use to retrieve data is on localhost:80

Any help is very much appreciated!

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

public api = 'http://127.0.0.1/';

storeServers(servers: any[]) {
 const headers: Headers = new Headers({
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  'http://127.0.0.1/',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
 });
 return this.http.post(this.api+'/Angular_6/http- start/api.php/testservers', servers, {headers: headers});
}

 getServers(){
  return this.http.get(this.api+'/Angular_6/http-start/api.php/testservers?transform=1');
 }
}
```

I solved the problem by adding a proxy file. See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjmZPPKaj6A

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable and configure the cors middleware of PHP-CRUD-API (set allowed origin in the PHP config) to allow cross domain requests. You can then see the OPTIONS request in the network tab of the developers tools of your browser. You should verify it is responding with a 200 OK status (and is not blocked by your webserver).

NB: I'm the author of PHP-CRUD-API

Comment: I've searched for config in PHP-CRUD-API. Do you mean this public function__construct($config)? And if so where do I set allowed origin? I'm sorry being not familiar with this PHP code

Comment: Please read the [README](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/blob/master/README.md) for instructions and feel free to submit an issue when you need help.